# Databound Listview not refreshing when set up with Parallel.Invoke

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, task-parallel-library, inotifypropertychanged

I have a Window with a TabControl in it. The TabControl contains 5 different TabItems. Each TabItem has its own ViewModel associated as its DataContext, while the Window has a DataContext that has all 5 TabItem's view models as properties. The problem I am having is setup. There is a noticeable lag when I launch the Window (from my MainWindow) and I have spent a good chunk of time refactoring my code and making it faster by running things in parallel, making fewer calls to the database and running Tasks on semi-expensive operations. Everything works great, except for one TabItem and its view model. For some reason, the view does not refresh itself properly.

For instance, I have a view model called `DiaryDescriptionViewModel` that takes in `List<SectionViewModel>` and does stuff with it, with the view bound to a result collection. It works fine. My troublesome view model is called `DiaryPayItemEditorViewModel` and it too takes in a `List<SectionViewModel>` and does stuff with it, with the view bound to a result collection. Neither view models perform the work on `List<SectionViewModel>` on worker threads or anything. However both view models are instanced and set up in parallel, which I wouldn't think be the root of the problem.

In my `DiaryPayItemEditorViewModel`, I have a `ObservableCollection<DiaryPayItemDetailViewModel>` that a ListView is data bound to. The ListView never displays the data, even though it exists. If I take all of my view model initialization code out of a `Parallel.Invoke` call, then it binds and displays the data.

My assumption here is that the view is initialized (`this.InitializeComponents`) before the `DiaryPayItemEditorViewModel` is fully set up, which should be fine. Since my view models all implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, the view should be notified that changes have taken place. For the life of me, I can't figure this out.

The following is the applicable source for the view Window view model (`DiaryEditorViewModel`), the view model who uses the same collection and works with binding (`DiaryDescriptionViewModel` and its child `DiaryDescriptionDetailsViewModel`) and then my troublesome view model (`DiaryPayItemEditorViewModel` and its child `DiaryPayItemDetailViewModel`).

### DiaryEditorViewModel.cs

```
public class DiaryEditorViewModel : BaseChangeNotify
{
    private DiaryViewModel diary;

    private Project project;

    private DiaryDetailsViewModel diaryDetailsViewModel;

    private DiaryDescriptionViewModel diaryDescriptionViewModel;

    private DiaryPayItemEditorViewModel diaryPayItemsViewModel;

    private DiaryEquipmentEditorViewModel diaryEquipmentEditorViewModel;

    private DiaryLaborViewModel diaryLaborViewModel;

    // This is the designated constructor used by the app.
    public DiaryEditorViewModel(Project project, Diary diary, UserViewModel user)
        : base(user)
    {
        // Instance a new diary view model using the provided diary.
        this.diary = new DiaryViewModel(diary, user);
        this.project = project;

        // Setup the repositories we will use.
        var repository = new ProjectRepository();
        var contractorRepository = new ContractorRepository();

        // Setup the temporary collections used by the repositories.
        var contractors = new List<Contractor>();
        var contractorViewModels = new List<ContractorViewModel>();
        var projectSections = new List<Section>();
        var bidItemCollection = new List<BidItem>();
        var subItemCollection = new List<SubItem>();
        var sectionViewModels = new List<SectionViewModel>();
        var equipmentCategories = new List<EquipmentCategory>();
        var equipmentFuelTypes = new List<EquipmentFuelType>();
        var equipmentList = new List<Equipment>();
        var equipmentViewModels = new List<EquipmentViewModel>();

        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Parallel.Invoke(
                // Fetch contractors for selected project.
                () =>
                {
                    contractors.AddRange(contractorRepository.GetContractorsByProjectId(diary.ProjectId));
                    equipmentCategories.AddRange(contractorRepository.GetEquipmentCategories());
                    equipmentFuelTypes.AddRange(contractorRepository.GetEquipmentFuelTypes());
                    equipmentList.AddRange(contractorRepository.GetEquipmentByProjectId(this.Project.ProjectId));

                    // Reconstruct the contractor->Equipment->FuelType & Category relationship.
                    contractorViewModels.AddRange(
                        contractors.Select(contractor =>
                            new ContractorViewModel(
                                contractor,
                                equipmentList.Where(equipment =>
                                    equipment.ContractorId == contractor.ContractorId).Select(e =>
                                        new EquipmentViewModel(
                                            e,
                                            contractor,
                                            equipmentCategories.FirstOrDefault(cat =>
                                                cat.EquipmentCategoryId == e.EquipmentCategoryId),
                                            equipmentFuelTypes.FirstOrDefault(f =>
                                                f.EquipmentFuelTypeId == e.EquipmentFuelTypeId))))));
                },

                () =>
                {
                    // Fetch all of the Sections, Bid-Items and Sub-items for the project
                    projectSections.AddRange(repository.GetSectionsByProjectId(project.ProjectId));
                    bidItemCollection.AddRange(repository.GetBidItemsByProjectId(project.ProjectId));
                    subItemCollection.AddRange(repository.GetSubItemsByProjectId(project.ProjectId));

                    // Reconstruct the Section->BidItem->SubItem hierarchy.
                    sectionViewModels.AddRange(
                        projectSections.Select(s =>
                            new SectionViewModel(project, s,
                                bidItemCollection.Where(b => b.SectionId == s.SectionId).Select(b =>
                                    new BidItemViewModel(project, b,
                                        subItemCollection.Where(si => si.BidItemId == b.BidItemId))))));
                }
                );

            // Once the parallel invocations are completed, instance all of the children view models
            // using the view model collections we just set up.
            Parallel.Invoke(
                // Fetch contractors for selected project.
                () =>
                    this.DiaryDetailsViewModel = new DiaryDetailsViewModel(
                        project, 
                        diary, 
                        user),
                () => // This view model works just fine, with same constructor signature.
                    this.DiaryDescriptionViewModel = new DiaryDescriptionViewModel(
                        project,
                        diary,
                        user,
                        sectionViewModels),
                () =>
                    this.DiaryPayItemEditorViewModel = new DiaryPayItemEditorViewModel(
                        project,
                        diary,
                        user,
                        sectionViewModels),
                () => // This view model does not notify the UI of changes to its collection.
                    this.DiaryEquipmentEditorViewModel = new DiaryEquipmentEditorViewModel(
                        project,
                        diary,
                        user,
                        contractorViewModels),
                () =>
                    // For the Labor view, we just pass the Contractor model collection rather than the view model collection
                    // since the Labor view does not need any of the additional equipment information.
                    this.DiaryLaborViewModel = new DiaryLaborViewModel(
                        project,
                        diary,
                        user,
                        contractors));
        });
    }

    public Project Project
    {
        get
        {
            return this.project;
        }

        set
        {
            this.project = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public DiaryViewModel Diary
    {
        get
        {
            return this.diary;
        }

        set
        {
            this.diary = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public DiaryDetailsViewModel DiaryDetailsViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return this.diaryDetailsViewModel;
        }

        set
        {
            this.diaryDetailsViewModel = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public DiaryDescriptionViewModel DiaryDescriptionViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return this.diaryDescriptionViewModel;
        }

        set
        {
            this.diaryDescriptionViewModel = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public DiaryPayItemEditorViewModel DiaryPayItemEditorViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return this.diaryPayItemsViewModel;
        }

        set
        {
            this.diaryPayItemsViewModel = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public DiaryLaborViewModel DiaryLaborViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return this.diaryLaborViewModel;
        }

        set
        {
            this.diaryLaborViewModel = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public DiaryEquipmentEditorViewModel DiaryEquipmentEditorViewModel
    {
        get
        {
            return this.diaryEquipmentEditorViewModel;
        }

        set
        {
            this.diaryEquipmentEditorViewModel = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

### DiaryDescriptionViewModel

This view model works just fine, with its `this.DiaryDescriptions` collection being bound to properly and displayed in the `ListView`

```
public class DiaryDescriptionViewModel : BaseDiaryViewModel, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private ObservableCollection<DiaryDescriptionDetailsViewModel> diaryDescriptions;

    private DiaryDescriptionDetailsViewModel selectedDiaryDescription;

    public DiaryDescriptionViewModel()
    {
    }

    public DiaryDescriptionViewModel(Project project, Diary diary, UserViewModel user, List<SectionViewModel> sections)
        : base(project, diary, user)
    {
        // Restore any previously saved descriptions.
        var diaryRepository = new DiaryRepository();
        List<DiaryDescription> descriptions = diaryRepository.GetDiaryDescriptionsByDiaryId(diary.DiaryId);

        this.ProjectSections = sections;

        // Reconstruct our descriptions
        this.diaryDescriptions = new ObservableCollection<DiaryDescriptionDetailsViewModel>();
        foreach (DiaryDescription description in descriptions)
        {
            SectionViewModel section = this.GetSectionContainingBidItemId(description.BidItemId);
            BidItemViewModel bidItem = section.GetBidItem(description.BidItemId);

            var details = new DiaryDescriptionDetailsViewModel(description, section, bidItem);
            details.PropertyChanged += ChildViewModelPropertyChanged;

            this.diaryDescriptions.Add(details);
        }

        this.diaryDescriptions.CollectionChanged += this.DiaryDescriptionsOnCollectionChanged;

        this.IsDirty = false;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<DiaryDescriptionDetailsViewModel> DiaryDescriptions
    {
        get
        {
            return this.diaryDescriptions;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                this.diaryDescriptions.CollectionChanged -= this.DiaryDescriptionsOnCollectionChanged;
                this.diaryDescriptions =
                    new ObservableCollection<DiaryDescriptionDetailsViewModel>(
                        value
                            .OrderBy(s => s.Section.Section)
                            .ThenBy(i => i.BidItem.BidItem.Number));

                this.diaryDescriptions.CollectionChanged += this.DiaryDescriptionsOnCollectionChanged;
            }
            else
            {
                this.diaryDescriptions = new ObservableCollection<DiaryDescriptionDetailsViewModel>();
            }

            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public DiaryDescriptionDetailsViewModel SelectedDiaryDescription
    {
        get
        {
            return this.selectedDiaryDescription;
        }

        set
        {
            // Always unsubscribe from events before replacing the object. Otherwise we end up with a memory leak.
            if (this.selectedDiaryDescription != null)
            {
                this.selectedDiaryDescription.PropertyChanged -= this.ChildViewModelPropertyChanged;
            }

            this.selectedDiaryDescription = value;

            if (value != null)
            {
                // If the description contains a biditem DiaryId, then we go fetch the section and biditem
                // associated with the diary description.
                if (value.BidItemId > 0)
                {
                    this.selectedDiaryDescription.Section = this.GetSectionContainingBidItemId(value.BidItemId);
                    this.selectedDiaryDescription.BidItem = this.selectedDiaryDescription.Section.GetBidItem(value.BidItemId);
                }

                // Subscribe to property changed events so we can set ourself to dirty.
                this.selectedDiaryDescription.PropertyChanged += this.ChildViewModelPropertyChanged;
                this.selectedDiaryDescription.IsDirty = false;
            }

            this.OnPropertyChanged();
            this.IsDirty = false;
        }
    }
```

### DiaryDescriptionDetailViewModel

Working child view model.

```
public class DiaryDescriptionDetailsViewModel : BaseChangeNotify
{
    private readonly DiaryDescription diaryDescription;

    private SectionViewModel section;

    private BidItemViewModel bidItem;

    public DiaryDescriptionDetailsViewModel(DiaryDescription description, SectionViewModel section = null, BidItemViewModel bidItem = null)
    {
        this.diaryDescription = description;

        if (description.BidItemId > 0)
        {
            this.section = section;
            this.bidItem = bidItem;
        }

        this.IsDirty = false;
    }

    public DiaryDescription Description
    {
        get
        {
            return this.diaryDescription;
        }
    }

    public int BidItemId
    {
        get
        {
            return this.diaryDescription.BidItemId;
        }
    }

    public BidItemViewModel BidItem
    {
        get
        {
            return this.bidItem;
        }

        set
        {
            this.bidItem = value;
            this.diaryDescription.BidItemId = value.BidItem.BidItemId;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public SectionViewModel Section
    {
        get
        {
            return this.section;
        }

        set
        {
            this.section = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

### DiaryPayItemEditorViewModel

And finally, the view model who is not having its collection rendered to the view.

```
public class DiaryPayItemEditorViewModel : BaseDiaryViewModel, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private ObservableCollection<DiaryPayItemDetailViewModel> diaryPayItemDetails;

    private DiaryPayItemDetailViewModel selectedDiaryPayItemDetail;

    private List<DiaryPayItem> allPayItemsForSelectedBidItem;

    private decimal sumOfAllPayItemsForBidItem;

    public DiaryPayItemEditorViewModel()
    {
    }

    public DiaryPayItemEditorViewModel(Project project, Diary diary, UserViewModel user, List<SectionViewModel> sections)
        : base(project, diary, user)
    {
        this.Initialize(project, sections);

        this.IsDirty = false;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<DiaryPayItemDetailViewModel> DiaryPayItemDetails
    {
        get
        {
            return this.diaryPayItemDetails;
        }

        set
        {
            this.diaryPayItemDetails = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public DiaryPayItemDetailViewModel SelectedDiaryPayItemDetail
    {
        get
        {
            return this.selectedDiaryPayItemDetail;
        }

        set
        {
            if (this.selectedDiaryPayItemDetail != null)
            {
                this.selectedDiaryPayItemDetail.PropertyChanged -= this.ChildViewModelPropertyChanged;
            }

            if (value != null)
            {
                value.PropertyChanged += this.ChildViewModelPropertyChanged;
            }

            this.selectedDiaryPayItemDetail = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private void Initialize(Project project, List<SectionViewModel> sections)
    {
        var repository = new DiaryRepository();
        var projectRepository = new ProjectRepository();
        this.DiaryPayItemDetails = new ObservableCollection<DiaryPayItemDetailViewModel>();

        this.ProjectSections = sections;

        // Repository calls to the database.
        List<DiaryPayItem> payItems = repository.GetDiaryPayItemsByDiaryId(this.Diary.DiaryId);
        var sectionItems = projectRepository.GetSectionHierarchy(project.ProjectId);

        // Temporary, needs to be refined.
        foreach (var diaryPayItem in payItems)
        {
            var subItem = sectionItems.SubItems.FirstOrDefault(sub => sub.SubItemId == diaryPayItem.SubItemId);
            var bidItems =
                sectionItems.BidItems.Where(bid => bid.BidItemId == subItem.BidItemId)
                    .Select(
                        bid =>
                            new BidItemViewModel(project, bid,
                                sectionItems.SubItems.Where(sub => sub.BidItemId == bid.BidItemId)));
            var section = new SectionViewModel(
                project,
                sectionItems.Sections.FirstOrDefault(s => bidItems.Any(bid => bid.BidItem.SectionId == s.SectionId)),
                bidItems);

            this.DiaryPayItemDetails.Add(
                new DiaryPayItemDetailViewModel(
                    diaryPayItem,
                    section,
                    bidItems.FirstOrDefault(bid => bid.BidItem.BidItemId == subItem.BidItemId),
                    subItem));
        }
    }
```

#### DiaryPayItemDetailViewModel - Child view model to the troublesome view model

```
public class DiaryPayItemDetailViewModel : BaseChangeNotify
{
    private DiaryPayItem diaryPayItem;

    private SectionViewModel selectedSection;

    private BidItemViewModel selectedBidItem;

    private SubItem selectedSubItem;

    public DiaryPayItemDetailViewModel(
        DiaryPayItem diaryPayItem, 
        SectionViewModel section, 
        BidItemViewModel bidItem,
        SubItem subItem)
    {
        this.DiaryPayItem = diaryPayItem;
        this.SelectedSection = section;
        this.SelectedBidItem = bidItem;
        this.SelectedSubItem = subItem;
    }

    public DiaryPayItem DiaryPayItem
    {
        get
        {
            return this.diaryPayItem;
        }
        set
        {
            this.diaryPayItem = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public SectionViewModel SelectedSection
    {
        get
        {
            return this.selectedSection;
        }
        set
        {
            this.selectedSection = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public BidItemViewModel SelectedBidItem
    {
        get
        {
            return this.selectedBidItem;
        }
        set
        {
            this.selectedBidItem = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public SubItem SelectedSubItem
    {
        get
        {
            return this.selectedSubItem;
        }
        set
        {
            this.selectedSubItem = value;
            this.DiaryPayItem.SubItemId = value.SubItemId;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

#### XAML for the DiaryDescription Tab Item.

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DiaryDescriptions}"
          SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedDiaryDescription}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Section.SectionName}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

#### XAML for Diary Pay Items tab item.

```
<ListView Name="PayItemListView"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DiaryPayItemDetails}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=SelectedBidItem.BidItem.Description}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

#### BaseChangeNotify

Lastly, to show my `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation, I present my base class. It wraps all calls to the event handlers in an `Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke()` action. This forces all event handler calls to be ran on the main thread so I don't have to worry about cross-thread issues in my inherited objects.

```
public class BaseChangeNotify : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool isDirty;

    private UserViewModel user;

    public BaseChangeNotify()
    {
    }

    public BaseChangeNotify(UserViewModel user)
    {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public bool IsDirty
    {
        get
        {
            return this.isDirty;
        }

        set
        {
            this.isDirty = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public UserViewModel User
    {
        get
        {
            return this.user;
        }
    }

    public virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        // Perform the IsDirty check so we don't get stuck in a infinite loop.
        if (propertyName != "IsDirty")
        {
            this.IsDirty = true; // Each time a property value is changed, we set the dirty bool.
        }

        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            // Invoke the event handlers attached by other objects.
            try
            {
                // When unit testing, this will always be null.
                if (Application.Current != null)
                {
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                        this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)));
                }
                else
                {
                    this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
```

If anyone could help me figure this out I would greatly appreciate it. I have been trying various things for the last two days and can't get it figured out. It's weird how one view model works fine, essentially performing the same kind of operation, and the other does not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why the downvote? I'd appreciate some feedback so I can improve on my questions in the future. I thought I was pretty thorough and detailed.

Answer (score 1):

The `DiaryEditorViewModel` is the view model to a DiaryEditorWindow. The DiaryPayItemEditorViewModel belongs to a user control that resides within the Window. Setting the data context in the XAML at the Window level, for the TabItem, resolved this issue. Setting the DataContext at the UserControl level caused view model to not bind properly.

I also tried setting the datacontext in the constructor, but that had the same issue. It would never bind. By setting the datacontext in the XAML of the TabItem associated with the troublesome view model, the problem was resolved. I don't understand why this is an issue. Since the view model fully implements the property changed event, I should be able to set the data context at any point, and adjust the values without a problem.

Eitherway, I have been able to solve this issue.